# How I start React project through terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, terminal

I am trying to create a new react-app using, `npx create-react-app <app name>` like this:

```sh
npx create-react-app new-app
```

But after downloading it is hanging over. I mean it is doing nothing. I've reinstalled `node.js` so that it is the latest version.

Final result I'm getting is:

```sh
    Creating a new React app in D:\DesktopD\aapp.

    Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
    Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

    > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall D:\DesktopD\aapp\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js       
    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

    > core-js@3.6.5 postinstall D:\DesktopD\aapp\node_modules\core-js
    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

    > core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall D:\DesktopD\aapp\node_modules\core-js-pure
    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

    + cra-template@1.0.3
    + react-scripts@3.4.3
    + react@16.13.1
    + react-dom@16.13.1
    added 1596 packages from 745 contributors and audited 1600 packages in 162.58s

    71 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details

    found 0 vulnerabilities
```

When I command "npm start" following errors are occuring:

```js
$ npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\2019\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-11T06_03_19_532Z-debug.log
```

Here is the above mentioned Log file.

```js
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'D:\\NodeJs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\NodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v12.19.0
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (D:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at D:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at D:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:116:5
4 verbose stack     at D:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:436:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (D:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:391:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (D:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:434:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (D:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (D:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:350:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (D:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:261:13)
5 verbose cwd D:\DesktopD\my-app3
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
7 verbose argv "D:\\NodeJs\\node.exe" "D:\\NodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
8 verbose node v12.19.0
9 verbose npm  v6.14.8
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here is the package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "aapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you succeeded at the end, when you try `npm start`...what happens?

Comment: @MwamiTovi                                                                                                                              
$ npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

'npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR!     C:\Users\2019\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10- 
                       11T07_38_44_508Z-debug.log'

Comment: OK, erase that `npm start` bit and instead show us what's in the `package.json`. Are you able to do that?

Comment: Is that the entire `package.json`?

Comment: Yes. @MwamiTovi

Comment: Then add this `"scripts": {  "start": "react-scripts start" },` to the `package.json` and then run `npm start` at the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

71 Packages needs funding which means these lists of the modules you have need contributions or donations of money to their projects.You can turn these off by this command

```
npm config set fund false --global
```

also stop core-js by this command

```
npm install --no-fund core-js
```